# Special characters do not work after changing the keyboard layout in 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, language-support, special-characters

I changed the keyboard layout with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. If I release <kbd>Alt</kbd> after the language change, but do not release the <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then special characters do not work. I need to release and press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> again.

How can I fix this?